# 5 tips to learn English easily

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Consider this sentence, please:

1. *5 tips **to learn English easily**.*

Q1): Is sentence 1) a complete sentence?

Q2): Is the infinitival clause(in bold) an adjective clause modifying the noun phrase "5 tips" or is it an adverbial clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `5 tips to learn English easily.`

Q2) Yes, that is a to-infinitival clause functioning as an adjective, modifying "tips".

Q1) No, it is not a complete sentence. An infinitival clause is subordinate, and there is no main clause for it to be subordinate to.

This is an example of a sentence with a main finite clause followed by that subordinate clause:
`Here are five tips to learn English easily.`

Though 1) is not a complete sentence, it will serve as a header for a list. It might be better to begin it with the small whole number '5' spelled out.

Comment: Which one is more idiomatic: "tip **to learn**" or "tip **for learning**"?

Comment: I think "for learning" sounds a little more natural.